# Initialize array in javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, constructor, three.js

I have a constructor and i want to initialize an array inside the object to be created. This array is supposed to contain a couple of objects.

```
        function Cluster3DObject(name){
            this.name = name;
            this.array = [];
        }

        Cluster3DObject.prototype.add = function(obj) {
            this.array.push(this.obj);

        };
```

Here i define the "class" and i have added one method "add" and it is supposed to push an object into this.array..

```
            var cluster = new Cluster3DObject("clster");

            var testObj = new THREE.CSS3DObject(testDiv);

            var testVector = new THREE.Vector3();

            cluster.add(testObj);
```

When i call the cluster.add method i get the "undefined is not a function error" but i can't seem to find out what i'm doing wrong?
i am new to using constructors..

Comment: No, the `add` method cannot cause this error. It's somewhere else. I'd check what `THREE` contains.

Answer (score 4):

It's not `this.obj`, just `obj`

```
Cluster3DObject.prototype.add = function(obj) {
     this.array.push(obj);
};
```

otherwise it seems fine, but that wouldn't really produce a `"undefined is not a function error"`, it would just push `undefined`, so the error probably comes from trying to use the array filled with `undefined` values ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0hy3ccgh/)